# Suppress notifications whilst testing shiny R app

Tags: r, testing, shiny, automated-tests

I'm using `shinytest` to create test snapshots of a shiny app.

Some long-running processes in the app that I'm testing produce notifications that fade after a set amount of time (using `showNotification()`) or progress bars (using the "cli" package).

This causes tests to fail if fading notifications have different transparencies, or if progress bars are at slightly different widths, when a snapshot is taken.

Is it possible to suppress notifications whilst a test is underway – perhaps by triggering a CSS rule?

Answer (score 1):

Run 'shinytest' as follows:

```
library(shinytest)
app <- ShinyDriver$new(".", loadTimeout = 1e+05,
                       shinyOptions = list(test.mode = TRUE))
```

Then, in your app, `getOption("shiny.testmode")` is `TRUE` when 'shinytest' is running the app. So what you can do is showing the notifications in your app server only if `getOption("shiny.testmode")` is not `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful for the `showNotification()` pop-ups, but is less easy to apply were progress bars are produced using functions from the "cli" package in functions called by the app – I wonder whether there's a solution that would capture those too?

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry I never used progress bars. Which functions are you talking about?

Comment: `cli::cli_progress_bar()` creates a progress notification in shiny, or a text progress bar if run from the terminal.  My app calls functions in other packages that use the cli interface to show progress bars.